# For the YOLO loss function, what is the calculation performed in order to obtain the value of the term 1objij?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, object-detection, loss-function, yolo

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the value of circled terms, what are the inputs/outputs I have to compare?

[image: Loss Function]

Let's take the first term for example, if I understand it correctly it goes something like this:

Let's say my predicted values for the first cell, first bounding box (yolov1 = 2 bbs) are

```
[pr, x, y, W, H]
[.7, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1]
```

and my true values are

```
[pr, x, y, W, H]
[1, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2]
```

That would make mean the formula goes something like this

5 * (**1 or 0**) ((0.6 - .5)^2 + (0.4 - 0.3)^2)

Can someone provide an example step by step on what are the metrics to determine  **1 or 0**?

Are we looking at the label from the training set image?
Are we looking at the predicted objectness score?
IoU?

According to the YOLO paper:

> 1objij : denotes that the jth bounding box predictor in cell i is
>   “responsible” for that prediction
>
> 1obji : Denotes if object appears in cell i

But this quote doesn't exactly help me answer my question...
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `1objij` is either `0` or `1`:

- It is always `0` if the cell is empty in the training data, in your example if the value for `pr` from training data is `0`. Note: In the training data the value for `pr` is either `0` or `1`, nothing else is possible for this value.
- If there is a `1` in the training data for `pr` it furthermore depends on the `IoU` of the predicted bounding boxes and the ground truth. Yolo predicts `B` bounding boxes for each cell, the highest `IoU` bounding box the value of the corresponding `1objij` is `1` for all other bounding box predictions it is `0`.

> Are we looking at the label from the training set image? Are we looking at the predicted objectness score? IoU?

- As I tried to answer `1objij` uses both `pr` from training data and `IoU` calculated from prediction and training data.
- `1obji` uses only `pr` from training data.

Answer (score -1):

As i understand, every grid cell, yolo predict 2 boxes,

```
box1 = [.7, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1]
box2 = [1, 0.61, 0.41, 0.21, 0.21]
```

Obviously the

```
IOU(box2,ground-truth box) > IOU(box1,ground-truth box)
```

so when we calulate loss, we do not consider box1, that means

```
1objij(i=0,j=0) = 0
1objij(i=0,j=1) = 1
```